# How to pass an element to jQuery post inside a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, loops

I have the following code:

```
for (_field in _fields) {
    $.post(
        '/api/fields',
        { id: _field.id },
        function(data, _field) {
            alert(data);
        } (data, _fields[_field)
    );
}
```

I have to pass the `_fields[_field]` element to the function that returns the data from the jQuery because loses the reference to the right object during the loop. The problem is that in defining that the `post` function should have a `_field` parameter, you also have to specify a parameter for data, or data will be overwritten with `_field`.

Currently data returns as `undefined` because I have no data object defined inside the loop. I also tried passing in `null`, but that also just returns `null`. I'm looking for a way to pass the element without overwriting the data returned from the post function.

Is there any way to fix this, or is there perhaps an alternative jQuery method that can do what's needed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want a function factory function — a function that creates a function:

```
for (_fieldName in _fields) {
    $.post('/api/fields',
    {
        // Unrelated, but I think this bit is wrong; shouldn't it be
        // `id: _fields[_fieldName].id` ? You're trying to use `.id` on
        // a string -- see below for a full update
        id: _fieldName.id
    },
    makeHandler(_fields[_fieldName])
    );
}
function makeHandler(field) {
    return function(data) {
        // Use `data` and `field` here
    };
}
```

Note that in the object initializer we're passing into `$.post`, we're *calling* `makeHandler` to it runs and returns the function we'll then pass into `$.post`. That function is then called when the `$.post` completes, and has access to the `data` argument that `$.post` gives it as well as the `field` argument to `makeHandler`, because it's a closure over the context of the call to `makeHandler`, which includes the `field` argument. More: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

---

Note that in the code above, I changed your variable `_field` to `_fieldName` to be more clear: The variable in `for..in` loops is a string, the *name* of a property. See also the comment, I think you were trying to use `.id` in the wrong place. Here's what I think you really wanted:

```
for (_fieldName in _fields) {
    _field = _fields[_fieldName];
    $.post('/api/fields',
    {
        id: _field.id
    },
    makeHandler(_field)
    );
}
function makeHandler(field) {
    return function(data) {
        // Use `data` and `field` here
    };
}
```

Also note that if `_fields` is an array, you shouldn't use `for..in` on it without safeguards. More: [*Myths and realities of `for..in`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html)