# How to get correct for loop variable in Ajax function in jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    $.post("ajax.php", {param: i}, function (response) {
        console.log(i);
    });
}
```

How to get correct i variable in `$.post` complete function, Can I pass variable to it?

Comment: Here is [answer][1] to your question - use factory function.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171106/how-to-pass-an-element-to-jquery-post-inside-a-loop

Comment: [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add an [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) to it, this will copy the outer `i` for each instance:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
  !function( i ){
    $.post("ajax.php", {param: i}, function (response) {
        console.log(i);
    });
  }( i );
}
```

**Edit**

As for the question in the comments:

In the above code I use the `!` to tell the parser, that there is a function expression to follow and not a function declaration. This is needed in order to have a IIFE, but you can use a whole lot of different ways to do so as mentioned by @Wayne.

For more details, have a look at this question:

- [What is the difference between a function expression vs declaration in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1013385/1169798)
- [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/1169798)

Comment: Besides `!`, `+`  `-`  `~` would do the same job

Comment: @Sirko - can you explain more? what is `!` for?

Comment: if your code works it is a perfect code. How is my code? longer but I think true.

Comment: @imsiso You have to tell the parse somehow, that this is a function expression and not a declaration (see, e.g., [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1013385/1169798)). In my answer I used a `!` to do so. In general there are plenty of ways to do this.

Comment: @Sirko - would `!` be same as using `var tmp=functio...`? and why i is still known in the ajax callback?

Comment: @imsiso As for the first question, yes, if you then call `tmp` in each loop. As for the second question: By using a function, the value is copied (as all primitives will be in JS) and hence inside the function the copied value will be used. Furthermore, you could look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/1169798) to see, why the callback sees the version of `i` created by the IIFE.

Comment: if `!function(i) {}(i);` equal to `(function(i) {}(i))`?

Comment: @吳承諺 In this context, it is.